# Server side script in C# return different time from what server clock is displaying

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am facing typical issue.My dedicated server clock showing 11 Am and datetime function in asp.net script returns 4pm time.

Please help how to resolve the issue.I need the function to return the server clock time.I dont know if its common issue i am facing it for first time.

Automatically syncronize with an internet time server :: CHECKED TICK
ntp2.ja.net

GMT-05 eastern time (US & Canada)

PIECE OF CODE::

```
           if (DateTime.Now.Hour >= 12 && Convert.ToDateTime(txtShipDate.Text.Trim()) < DateTime.Today.AddDays(2))
            {
                flag = false;
            }

            if (DateTime.Now.Hour < 12 && Convert.ToDateTime(txtShipDate.Text.Trim()) < DateTime.Today.AddDays(1))
            {
                flag = false;
            }
```

regards

Comment: What time zone are you in? What time zone are you trying to display?

Comment: we need more information to help you... can you post the code?

Comment: i have added piece of code and server clock setting.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using two different properties of DateTime (or simply Date) class: Now and UtcNow.
Try to use UtcNow, if you use Now, or vice versa.